# How to get date for tomorrow in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

`SELECT datetime('now')` is for current date.

What will be the query for tomorrow, last 7 days, and next 7 days?

Comment: This looks like its not really an Android or Java problem, but SQL. Is it SQLite you're using? In which case I think you can do `datetime('now', '+7 days')` etc.

Comment: What if you try `SELECT date('now','-7 days')`  and `SELECT date('now','+7 days')`?

Answer (score 0):

select getutcdate() + n where if n is any positive number it is for next day and so on otherwise it's the past.